# Yii2, Unable to write cache file , but only for one .bin file

Tags: caching, yii2

My entire log file is thrown with such an error as

```
Unable to write cache file '/server/path/public_html/frontend/runtime/cache/5c/5c6160ccf5471521467ec8731281dbc4.bin': file_put_contents(/server/path/public_html/frontend/runtime/cache/5c/5c6160ccf5471521467ec8731281dbc4.bin): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I thought it was a problem with access rights in the folder. but I noticed that the cache works fine and swears only on this one file `5c/5c6160ccf5471521467ec8731281dbc4.bin`

why can this be? access are `drwxrwxr-x`

Comment: Did you tried to just delete this file?

Comment: i can delete this file. it's yii2 try to add cache file to folder.

Comment: Is Yii trying to create or edit this file? Maybe it was already created with incorrect permissions and that is why Yii can't edit it.

Comment: `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R frontend/runtime` && `sudo chmod 755 -R frontend/runtime` can you try it, this code change directory owner to www-data and permission to 755 (drwxr-xr-x). Because, if you use nginx or apache web-server, it's working with www-data user,